# How to convert an Expression<Func<T, bool>> to a Predicate<T>

Tags: c#, expression, predicate

I have a method that accepts an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` as a parameter.  I would like to use it as a predicate in the List.Find() method, but I can't seem to convert it to a Predicate which List takes.  Do you know a simple way to do this?

```
public IList<T> Find<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : class, new()
{
    var list = GetList<T>();

    var predicate = [what goes here to convert expression?];

    return list.Find(predicate);
}
```

**Update**

Combining answers from tvanfosson and 280Z28, I am now using this:

```
public IList<T> Find<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : class, new()
{
    var list = GetList<T>();

    return list.Where(expression.Compile()).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
Func<T, bool> func = expression.Compile();
Predicate<T> pred = t => func(t);
```

Edit: per the comments we have a better answer for the second line:

```
Predicate<T> pred = func.Invoke;
```

Comment: Yeah, func.Invoke looks better.

Answer (score 37):

Another options which hasn't been mentioned:

```
Func<T, bool> func = expression.Compile();
Predicate<T> predicate = new Predicate<T>(func);
```

This generates the same IL as

```
Func<T, bool> func = expression.Compile();
Predicate<T> predicate = func.Invoke;
```

Comment: why this only has 12 votes? you ungrateful peasants! It is he, Jon Skeet. Heed his words!!!!

Answer (score 28):

I'm not seeing the need for this method.  Just use Where().

```
 var sublist = list.Where( expression.Compile() ).ToList();
```

Or even better, define the expression as a lambda inline.

```
 var sublist = list.Where( l => l.ID == id ).ToList();
```

Comment: Using Where() instead of Find() is what I needed to do.  However your first example needs to use expression.Compile() instead of just expression. Thanks.

Comment: Updated.  I neglected the fact that Where takes a Func<T,bool>.

Comment: acctually you can use var sublist = list.Where(expression);