# NSubstitute not matching Linq Expression

Tags: linq, repository-pattern, linq-expressions, nsubstitute

I am implementing a repository pattern Query class and testing using NSubstitute.

Repository interface:

```
public interface IMyRepository
{
    IQueryable<T> Query<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter) where T : class;
}
```

DateTimeProvider interface:

```
public interface IMyDateTimeProvider
{
    DateTime GetDateNow();
}
```

Application interface:

```
public interface IMyApplication
{
    List<Thing> GetThingsByQuery(int status);
}
```

Application implementation:

```
public class MyApplication : IMyApplication
{
    private readonly IMyRepository myRepository;

    private readonly IMyDateTimeProvider myDateTimeProvider;

    public MyApplication(IMyRepository myRepository, IMyDateTimeProvider myDateTimeProvider)
    {
        this.myRepository = myRepository;
        this.myDateTimeProvider = myDateTimeProvider;
    }

    public List<Thing> GetThingsByQuery(int status)
    {
        var createdDate = this.myDateTimeProvider.GetDateNow();

        return this.myRepository.Query<Thing>(t => t.CreatedDate == createdDate && t.Status == status).ToList();
    }
}
```

Test:

```
[TestClass]
public class ApplicationTest
{
    private IMyApplication myApplication;

    private IMyDateTimeProvider myDateTimeProvider;

    private IMyRepository myRepository;

    [TestMethod]
    public void QueriesRepository()
    {
        // Arrange
        var createdDate = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);

        this.myDateTimeProvider.GetDateNow().Returns(createdDate);

        const int Status = 1;

        // Act
        this.myApplication.GetThingsByQuery(Status);

        // Assert
        this.myRepository.Received().Query<Thing>(t => t.CreatedDate == createdDate && t.Status == Status);
    }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitialize()
    {
        this.myRepository = Substitute.For<IMyRepository>();

        this.myDateTimeProvider = Substitute.For<IMyDateTimeProvider>();

        this.myApplication = new MyApplication(this.myRepository, this.myDateTimeProvider);
    }
}
```

But the test fails with the following message:

```
NSubstitute.Exceptions.ReceivedCallsException: Expected to receive a call matching:
    Query<Thing>(t => ((t.CreatedDate == value(MySolution.Test.ApplicationTest+<>c__DisplayClass0).createdDate) AndAlso (t.Status == 1)))
Actually received no matching calls.
Received 1 non-matching call (non-matching arguments indicated with '*' characters):
    Query<Thing>(*t => ((t.CreatedDate == value(MySolution.Application.MyApplication+<>c__DisplayClass0).createdDate) AndAlso (t.Status == value(MySolution.Application.MyApplication+<>c__DisplayClass0).status))*)
```

The DateTime and Status are being parsed into `value()` which are different between the Application and the Test.

Why is this? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

For complicate expressions if often find it easier to assert on captured arguments by using [callbacks](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/callbacks/) than with `Received()`. An (incomplete) example:

```
Expression<Func<Thing, bool>> receivedFilter receivedFilter = null;
myRepository.When(x => x.Query<Thing>(Arg.Any<...>))
  .Do(x => receivedQuery = x.Arg<Expression<Func<Thing, bool>>>());
```

Then, assert on the captured filter expression. It might actually simpler to just execute the expression's filter func (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217749/how-to-convert-an-expressionfunct-bool-to-a-predicatet))

```
Func<Thing, bool> predicate = receivedFilter.Compile();
var matchingThing = new Thing 
  { CreatedDate = createdData, Status = Status };
// assert matching
predicate(matchingThing).Should().BeTrue();

// assert non.matching
predicate(nonMatchingThing).Should().BeFalse();
```

This approach seems to make the test a little more black-boxed but this is in general not a bad thing.

Comment: Beautiful and simple approach.

Answer (score 0):

The default equality comparer for an Expression is being used (referential equality):

eg, the expression ``` (t => t.CreatedDate == createdDate && t.Status == Status``) ``` in:

```
this.myRepository.Received().Query<Thing>(t => t.CreatedDate == createdDate  
                                            && t.Status == Status          );
```

Is a different instance to the expression in:

```
return this.myRepository.Query<Thing>(t => t.CreatedDate == createdDate  
                                        && t.Status == status          ).ToList();
```

To fix validate this method call check out [argument matchers within NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/actions-with-arguments/).

But as an example:

```
Func<Expression<Thing, bool>, bool> validator = 
    // TODO this needs to be written properly, based on the expression, 
    // not its string representation
    e => e.Body.ToString() == "t.CreatedDate == createdDate  
      && t.Status == Status"; 
this.myRepository.Received().Query<Thing>(Arg.Is<Expression<Thing, bool>>(validator));
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about implementing that. I have tried `this.myRepository.Received().Query<Thing>(t => t.CreatedDate == Arg.Any<DateTime>() && t.Status == Arg.Any<int>());` and `this.myRepository.Received().Query<Thing>(t => t.CreatedDate == Arg.Is(createdDate) && t.Status == Arg.Is(Status));` but both are still using `value()` and failing

Comment: I couldn't get your example to compile. This compiles but the test fails with the exact same error: `Expression<Func<Thing, bool>> validator = t => t.CreatedDate == createdDate && t.Status == Status;` and `this.myRepository.Received().Query<Thing>(Arg.Is<Expression<Func<Thing, bool>>>(validator));`

Comment: In fact, ReSharper then states that the declarations aren't required and the .Received becomes `this.myRepository.Received().Query(Arg.Is(validator));` but still fails the test

Comment: My example was meant as an example, you can change validator to be: `Func<Expression<Thing, bool>, bool> validator = e => true` which will allow the test to pass, and will verify that the method was called, but not with the correct expression...

Comment: I can test that the method was called using `this.myRepository.Received().Query(Arg.Any<Expression<Func<Thing, bool>>>());` but I do actually want to test that the correct query is being used.